# How to sort , filter and display model data using week number in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I would like to sort my model's data on a week number for example when user logins user will see current week number and associated data and user should be able to select previous week number and get all past data as well also week starts on Sunday and ends on Saturday (considering 1 week)

Select Week :[2021 - 30 ] <- week number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter it such way:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

itemsList = Model_Name.objects.filter(user=request.user, created_date__gte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=7))
```

Comment: thanks bro  for answering here how we will set  every sunday as new week start

Comment: `import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now.strftime("%A"))`
this will give you the day's name. Then you can conditionally check the start and end of the week.

Answer (score 0):

I have got similar problem in my task and I solved it in simple steps:
**#django #django-models #django-views #problem-solving**

```
def get_weeks(request):
    week = now().isocalendar()
   
    if Event.objects.filter(start_date__week=week.week).exists():
        instances=Event.objects.filter(start_date__week=week.week)
```